# How do we move a result obtained from one function into another

Tags: haskell, ghci

Hi I am new to **Haskell** and I  came across a question which I am unsure how I would go about solving it. **Note: I am doing all this in a test.hs file and then loading that file using cmd**

The program will first ask the user to input a list of numbers ranging between 8-10 digits. then it will remove the last number from what you entered. **Eg if I typed in 236453110** I will get an output of **23646311.**

Then the problem I am having is recalling the output I got to another set of instructions. In which it will take every odd digit of the number **23646311.** and double it. So It should get and output of **4312412321.** Notice how if I double some of the **odd digits not numbers I get values above 12.** Well these values acutally get simiplified. so if i got 12 after I doubled the digit it would become  12 = 1+2= **3**

```
lastdigit :: Integer -> Integer
lastdigit x = x`div`10

doubleOdd (x:xs) = (2*x):(doubleEven xs)
doubleOdd [] = []
doubleEven (x:xs) = x:(doubleOdd xs)
doubleEven [] = []
```

I have been able to do the parts separately such as the function last digit will remove the last digit from the number you entered. As well as the double Odd function will double every Odd digit **Not Number**.

So to re summarise what I am asking help for is when I use my last digit function I want it to automatically go the the next function of doubleOdd and Double each of the odd Integers.**Note I do not want to code in prelude just using a text.hs file and loading that file on cmd**

Comment: What have you tried to acheive this? Could you post your code?

Comment: Thats what I am saying I have done the parts separately but I have no idea on how to move the result obtained into the other function

Comment: Ok, here's a tip: [`let` and `where`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where).

Comment: @cars: When so much of your question body overlaps, it seems to me that you have not understood the answer given and repeat the question, rather than ask a new question or ask elaborating questions as comments to the old one.